# git push で固まる

Tags: git, windows-10, git-bash

cloneした後、ファイルを編集しaddとcommitをしてpushしようとしたらpushでユーザー名もパスワードも尋ねられないまま処理が止まってしまいます。エラーメッセージも何も出力されないです。どうすればいいでしょうか。
ちなみに仮想マシンのUbuntu上で上記の作業を行うとうまくいきました。

環境はWindows10のGit Bushで作業しています。
どうすればいいでしょうか、ご教示お願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

質問するときは環境に関する情報を詳しく記述しましょう。

- [技術系メーリングリストで質問するときのパターン・ランゲージ](https://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html#env)

Git for Windowsのバージョンによって、手順が異なることがあります。

おそらく資格情報マネージャーのモジュールが正常に動作していないことが原因と思われます。似たような報告が英語版Stack Overflowにも挙がっています。

- [github - git 2.32 git push -u origin master Nothing happens - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67960886/git-2-32-git-push-u-origin-master-nothing-happens)

古いバージョンのGit for Windowsでは、インストーラーの「Configuring extra options」画面にて「Enable Git Credential Manager」にチェックを入れておくことで、.NET Frameworkベースの「Git Credential Manager」がデフォルトで使用されるようになっていましたが、現在はGitHubの旧パスワード認証の廃止に伴い、後継となる.NET Coreベースの「[Git Credential Manager Core](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core)」が推奨されています。

- [build-extra/ReleaseNotes.md at main · git-for-windows/build-extra](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/main/ReleaseNotes.md#changes-since-git-for-windows-v2290-october-19th-2020)

新しいGit for Windowsのインストーラーの「Choose a credential helper」画面では、新しいGit Credential Manager Coreがデフォルトで選択されていますが、Git for Windows v2.32.0 現在、この新しいManager Coreが正常に機能していないように思われます。
（該当モジュールは "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-credential-manager-core.exe"）

Manager Coreの問題の解決方法は不明ですが、代替として「wincred」を使用することで暫定回避できると思います。
（該当モジュールは "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-credential-wincred.exe"）

TortoiseGitでは「Settings」→「Git」→「Credential」の、「Helper」にて
「wincred」/「manager」/「manager-core」を選択できるようになっています。

```
$ git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

認証ダイアログで入力した認証情報は、Windowsの「資格情報マネージャー」で管理されます。
認証情報を削除したい場合は、「コントロールパネル」→「ユーザーアカウント」→「資格情報マネージャー」→「Windows資格情報」にて削除することができます。

Comment: ご提供いただいた方法でwincredを選択してpushしてみたのですが、状況は変わりませんでした。

Comment: 回答にも記述していますが、使っているバージョンが何なのかくらい書きましょうよ。

Comment: 失礼しました、2.32.0を使用していました。バージョン2.31.0をインストールしなおしてうまくいくので2.31.0を使用して回避しています。